# ibm WebSphere Application Server V8.5.0 console

Tags: aix, ibm-was, ibm-installation-manager

Please help!
I have installed IBM Websphere Application Server V8.5.0 on a AIX 7 machine, via IBM Install Manager 1.5.2, everything goes quiet good, until I launch the web console of administration, it doesn't show all the menus (Servers, Applications, Services)!!!

Comment: Did you at least looked in the logs, or just posted 'please help' on first problem you had?

Comment: I am new in the field, and this is my first post question in stackoverflow, it is nice of you to answer me, but could tell me where I can find this log files?

Comment: [Using basic or traditional message logs to troubleshoot applications](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/ttrb_mglogs.html?lang=en). You have to work on your Google-fu skills a bit ;-)

Comment: I check these log files : native_stderr.log, native_stdout.log, start_server.log, SystemErr.log, SystemOut.log. The last one, SystemOut.log contains : [4/2/15 13:29:49:160 CEST] 0000005d servlet       E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service SRVE0014E: Uncaught service() exception root cause /secure/layouts/detailTitleLayout.jsp: com.ibm.websphere.servlet.error.ServletErrorReport: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Define tag cannot set a null value

Comment: aused by: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Define tag cannot set a null value
[4/3/15 10:18:35:180 CEST] 0000005d webcontainer  E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.internal.WebContainer handleRequest SRVE0255E: A WebGroup/Virtual Host to handle /favicon.ico has not been defined.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I find the source of the problem! it is due to the port number used to access the IBM websphere console, which is 9044 by default.

Anyway, thanks Gas :)